# C# linq null question

Tags: c#, linq, null, nullreferenceexception

Could someone explain me how can this be possible:

```
foreach (var pair in Expected.Zip(
         Actual, (x, y) => new { Expected = x, Actual = y }))
{
    // No match for a 'null' series.
    if (pair.Actual == null) yield return 0;

    var actualPaths = pair.Actual.Images.Select(x => x.Path).ToList();
}
```

This code (in `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008`) stops on line `var actualPaths = ...` and says that `pair.Actual` equals `null`, therefore raising a `NullReferenceException`.

***How is this even possible? Am I missing something?***

Comment: How does it say that `pair.Actual` is null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After your `if`, the rest of the code keeps running.

You need to add `continue;`, or put the rest of the code in an `else` block.